# Read data from a CSV file in S3 bucket and store it in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3

I am trying to read a csv file from S3 bucket and store its content into a dictionary. 
Sample csv file data. I want to use my first row as key and subsequent rows as value.

```
name,origin,dest
xxx,uk,france
yyyy,norway,finland
zzzz,denmark,canada
```

I am using the below code which is storing the entire row in a dictionary. But I want to loop through each row and store each field in a row as key value pair.

{'name':'xxx','origin':'uk','dest':'france'}

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = 'bucket_name', Key = 'logs/log.csv')
lines = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8").replace("'", '"')
lines = lines.splitlines()
if (isinstance(lines, str)):
        lines = (lines)

docData = {}
for line in lines:
        docData['content'] = str(line)

print(docData)
```

Comment: You need to split each line with separator as `,` which will give you an iterable like `['name', 'origin', 'dest']`. Then you can use either builtin [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function or [generator expression](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) to get each value from subsequent lines and create dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = 'bucket_name', Key = 'logs/log.csv')
lines = obj['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
```

produces the csv's contents as a string, then you can use the standard library's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module to get a list of dicts.

```
import csv
import io

buf = io.StringIO(lines)
reader = csv.DictReader(buf)
rows = list(reader)
```

Comment: Thanks @snakecharmerb. Is there a way to do this without using csv module?. I trying to process log files which can be in .csv or .txt format. So, I am looking for ways to achieve this without the modules.

Comment: The `DictReader` can handle any character as a field separator.  For example, to use a tab (`'\t'`) as the separator you would set it like this `reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')`.